# Как создать Django-суперпользователя внутри Docker

Tags: python, django, docker

Имеется сервер, запускающийся через docker-compose. Нужно перед запуском сервера создать суперпользователя, чтобы можно было зайти в админку. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Обязательно перед запуском? Я так обычно создаю: `docker exec -it CONTAINER python manage.py createsuperuser`

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно вручную создавать, то такой командой:

```
docker-compose exec -ti service-name python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Тут `service-name` имя сервиса, как оно указано в `docker-compose.yml` файле.

Если нужно это делать перед стартом сервера, то нужно это делать с помощью опции `command` в определении сервиса. Допустим у вас сейчас сервис типа такого:

```
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn my.wsgi:application --settings=my.settings.conf
```

Тогда можно добавить команду:

```
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    environement:
      - DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=$DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD
    command: python manage.py createsuperuser && gunicorn my.wsgi:application --settings=my.settings.conf
```

Пароль для пользователя можно передать установив переменную окружения `DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD`  перед запуском `docker-compose up`.

Answer (score 0):

Отредактируйте Dockerfile, добавив туда вызов createsuperuser с переменными окружения.

```
RUN DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=Tr0ub4dor@3 python manage.py createsuperuser --noinput administator
```